# Magento Admin Grid Field Custom filter issue

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have created Magento Admin module with Grid and field having custom filter.

```
    $this->addColumn('diff', array(
        'header'    =>'Diff.',
        'align'     =>'left',
        'type' => 'number',
        'index'     =>'diff',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_diffFilter'),
    ));
```

Collection having group by as below:

`$collection->getSelect()->group(array('main_table.order_id'));`

Custom Filter function as below:

```
protected function _diffFilter($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $_filter_data = $column->getFilter()->getValue();               

    if($_filter_data["from"]!=''){
        $collection->getSelect()->having('ROUND((main_table.base_cost-main_table.base_price)*100/main_table.base_cost) >= ?', $_filter_data["from"]);           
    }

    if($_filter_data["to"]!=''){
        $collection->getSelect()->having('ROUND((main_table.base_cost-main_table.base_price)*100/main_table.base_cost) <= ?', $_filter_data["to"]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Using this function if i load admin grid it's throwing below error:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.base_cost' in 'having clause'`

But i grab select query `$collection->getSelect()` using this and then run to MySQL directly then, it is working fine, but it only throwing error from Magento.

I did lots of research but it's not working at all with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` clauses are used to filter the results of a grouped query. If you want to filter for columns in the table, use a `WHERE` clause:

```
protected function _diffFilter($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $_filter_data = $column->getFilter()->getValue();               

    if($_filter_data["from"]!=''){
        $collection->getSelect()->where('ROUND((main_table.base_cost-main_table.base_price)*100/main_table.base_cost) >= ?', $_filter_data["from"]);           
    }

    if($_filter_data["to"]!=''){
        $collection->getSelect()->where('ROUND((main_table.base_cost-main_table.base_price)*100/main_table.base_cost) <= ?', $_filter_data["to"]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it has SQL group query so that's why i used having clause, please refer updated question above.

Comment: The filtering you're trying to do is still not appropriate in a `HAVING` clause. Please list out the full query you're trying to produce. Also, if you look at the stack trace, is the error produced when loading the data or counting the results?